How to get quotient groups or other mathematical structures from modules?
I'm trying to use agda libraries for groups to do some examples of monomorphisms. I know how to import ℚ and ℤ, but I would also like to get the quotient group ℚ / ℤ, to show that the natural quotient π is a monomorphism. I know there are some modules that have "quotient groups" (like this or this), but I have no idea how to use them or what to do. I only see the code, but I don't see examples. I don't care about the code, I just want to use the constructions.
import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as Eq
open Eq using (_≡_; refl; sym; trans; cong; subst)
open Eq.≡-Reasoning
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; zero; suc; _+_; _*_; _∸_; _≤_; s≤s; z≤n)
open import Data.Nat.Properties using
  (+-assoc; +-identityˡ; +-identityʳ; *-assoc; *-identityˡ; *-identityʳ; *-distribʳ-+; *-distribˡ-+; *-comm; +-comm)
open import Function using (_∘_)
open import Data.Rational.Base using (ℚ)
open import Data.Integer.Base using (ℤ)

_∼_ : ∀ {A B : Set} → (f : A → B) → (g : A → B) → Set
(_∼_) {A} {B} f g = ∀ (x : A) → (f x ≡ g x)

isMono◦ : ∀ {A B : Set} → (A → B) → Set₁
isMono◦ {A} f = ∀ {C : Set} (g1 g2 : C → A) → ((f ∘ g1) ∼ (f ∘ g2)) → (g1 ∼ g2)

-- Question: how to get ℚ / ℤ ?
π : ℚ → ℚ / ℤ


Please ask a specific question. Which library are you asking about? At least for cubical the code seems pretty self-explanatory: you give _/_ a Group G and a NormalSubgroup of G and you get the quotient group.

But I dont know how to use the library. When I try to use "/" I get:
Not in scope:
/
(did you mean 'Data.Rational.Base./'?)
So I need help from zero, dont assume I know how to usea library (cubical or any other).

If your question is about using Agda libraries, then edit it to say so; no need to talk about quotient groups. But that would be a bad question, because it is easily answered by a web search, unless you describe a specific problem you are having with installing the cubical library. And of course you need to open import Cubical.Algebra.Group.QuotientGroup at the top of your file for _/_ to be in scope.

You'll probably also need to change your existing code to use the definitions from the cubical library instead of the stdlib.
